# In AutoCAD, is there a way to determine the rotation type for a shape in a LinetypeTableRecord using .net?

Tags: .net, autocad

AutoCAD allows three different types of rotations for shapes and text in complex linetypes.  In a linetype definition file (*.lin), the rotation types are "A" for an absolute rotation based upon the UCS, "R" for a rotation relative to the tangent to the line at the shape insertion point, and "U" for text that is also rotated relative to the tangent but always stays upright.  My question is, how can the rotation type be determined from the LineTypeTableRecord?  Or, is it even necessary?

It has occurred to me that the "R" rotation is somewhat obsolete unless there is a specific situation where you want the text or shape to align with the line, but don't care if the shape or text is upside-down when the drawing is viewed normally.  (This actually could be necessary for things like roadway centerline alignments.)  I think the "A" rotation can be determined from the ShapeIsUcsOrientedAt(i) property (True = "A").  But then there remains differentiating between "R" and "U".  Is this possible using .net?  If not, I will probably just regard everything that is not "A" as a "U".

BTW, I am trying to write an add-in program that runs through the linetype table and writes a *.lin file for all linetypes in a drawing. This is really just to see if I could do it, but it could have a more useful application later.  So far, it all works except the rotation type.